# NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I have deposit and wallet models in my rails admin. I am using wallet in deposit model as:

```
wal=Wallet.where(user_id: self.user_id)
wal.balance = wal.balance + self.amount
wal.save!
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#edit
```

The result of

```
puts wal.inspect
```

is

```
<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Wallet id: 1, balance: 200, user_id: 22, created_at: "2019-03-20 04:57:45", updated_at: "2019-03-20 06:43:32">]>
```

I found the solution, but I don't think its a proper approach

```
wal=Wallet.where(user_id: self.user_id)
wal[0].balance = wal[0].balance + self.amount
wal[0].save!
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.where` always returns a relation and not an object. The relation is basically an array of objects. Regardless if your search returns one,zero or many objects.

So the clean way of doing this is similar to your approach. You just select the object in the index 0 position of the relation array.

```
wal = Wallet.where(user_id: self.user_id).first
```

Another approach could be that you add a relation to the user model. Assumption would be that you make sure User always has just exactly one wallet and you have the user available.

```
# model
has_one :wallet
# controller
user = User.find(self.user_id)
wal = user.wallet
```

Find always returns one object (if it exists) since there can only be one.
Also an approach could be `.find_by`. Its similar to find but works for other object fields. For this you have to make sure that there is only one wallet per user since `find_by` returns just the first object even if there are multiple objects that match the query.

```
Wallet.find_by(user_id: self.user_id)
```

The last 2 examples have the advantage that they return a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` when there is no match. The `.where` returns only an empty relation array.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot.